# Getting line by line an integer stream to different arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have the following inputs:

> 23 34 43 56 45
> 100 73

I want to input these two strings in different arrays integer arrays using pointer since the input size is apriori unknown.

I have written the following code, but I cannot get the integers into any of the two arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define lent(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
#define Malloc(n, type) (type *)malloc((unsigned)((n) * sizeof(type)))
#define Realloc(ptr, n, type) (type *)realloc(ptr, (n) * sizeof(type))

void getInt_Stream(int *ptr)
{
    int i = 0;
    ptr = Malloc(i+1, int);
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    while ((c != EOF) && (c != '\n'))
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            ptr[i] = ptr[i] * 10 + (c - '0');
        }
        else if (c == ' ')
        {
            i++;
            ptr = Realloc(ptr, i+1,int);
            ptr[i] = 0;
        }
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int *arr1, *arr2;
    getInt_Stream(arr1);
    getInt_Stream(arr2);
    int n1 = lent(arr1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        printf(" arr1[%d] =%d\n", i, *(arr1+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I am getting some errors and warnings when I compile the program using 
`gcc prog.c -o prog -Wall -Wextra`.

Please help with some hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Vagish I have used macros. See the macros at the top. Thanks for pointing out the error for ```arr``` its ```arr1 ```.

Comment: Try instead `fgets` to read the whole line, then use `strtok` to extract words, then `sscanf` to convert to integer.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani is there any way to get the number of elements in an array pointed by the pointer? My ```lent``` macro gives some error and warning with ```-Wall -Wextra``` options in gcc.

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * get integer values from the file stream
 * return the pointer to the array of integers
 * the size of the array is stored in *n
 */
int *
getInt_Stream(FILE *fp, int *n)
{
    char str[BUFSIZ];           // line buffer of the input stream
    char *tk;                   // pointer to each token
    char delim[] = " ";         // delimiter of the tokens
    int *arr = NULL;            // array of intergers
    int count = 0;              // token counter

    if (NULL == (fgets(str, BUFSIZ, fp))) {
                                // read a line and assign str
        perror("fgets");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (tk = strtok(str, delim); tk != NULL; tk = strtok(NULL, delim)) {
                                // get token one by one
        if (NULL == (arr = realloc(arr, (count + 1) * sizeof(int)))) {
                                // allocate memory for the array
            perror("realloc");
            exit(1);
        }
        arr[count] = (int)strtol(tk, (char **)NULL, 10);
                                // assign the array element to int
        count++;
    }
    *n = count;                 // number of the elements
    return arr;                 // pointer to the array
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *arr1, *arr2;
    int n1, n2;
    char *filename = argv[1];
    FILE *fp;
    int i;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s file.txt\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(filename, "r"))) {
        perror(filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    arr1 = getInt_Stream(fp, &n1);
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        printf("arr1[%d] = %d\n", i, arr1[i]);
    }
    arr2 = getInt_Stream(fp, &n2);
    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        printf("arr2[%d] = %d\n", i, arr2[i]);
    }

    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Output for the provided file:

```
$ ./a.out file.txt 
arr1[0] = 23
arr1[1] = 34
arr1[2] = 43
arr1[3] = 56
arr1[4] = 45
arr2[0] = 100
arr2[1] = 73
```

Comment: A `for` loop is a better solution for this kind of tokenizing, because all parts are near each other that belong to each other: `for (tk = strtok(str, delim); tk != NULL; tk = strtok(NULL, delim)) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @thebusybee thanks for the suggestion. That's right. I've updated my code accordingly.